# Allowing "0" in an input number type field when requiring fields for a non native form submission

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a picture framing calculator.  I'm running into a problem making the input fields `required`.  The `required` attribute would only do something if I were using a native form submission, essentially letting the `<form>` element drive the form submission. Instead I've opted to use this **:**

```css
#height {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name "viewport" content="width=device-width,

        initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>I Was Framed - Calculator</title>



  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400i,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <sides>

    <section>

      <form id="frm1" action="/index.html" method="post">

        <fieldset>

          <legend>

            I Was Framed Calculator

          </legend>



          <label for="frameWidth">Frame Width:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="wf" id="wf">
          <select name="wff" id="wff">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
          </select>

          <label for="frameHeight">Frame Height:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="hf" id="hf">
          <select name="hff" id="hff">

            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
          </select>



          <label for="pictureWidth">Picture Width:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="wp"
            id="wp">
          <select name="wpf" id="wpf">

            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
          </select>

          <label for="pictureHeight">Picture Height:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="hp"
            id="hp">
          <select name="hpf" id="hpf">

            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
          </select><br>

          <label for="matOverlap">Mat Overlap:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="o" id="o">
          <select name="of" id="of">

            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
          </select>

          <br>


          <br>
          <input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Calculate" name="cmdCalc" />

        </fieldset>

      </form>

    </section>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/fractional@1.0.0/index.js"></script>

    <script>
      function calc()

      {

        var wf = eval(document.getElementById('wf').value)

        var wff = eval(document.getElementById('wff').value)

        var hf = eval(document.getElementById('hf').value)

        var hff = eval(document.getElementById('hff').value)

        var wp = eval(document.getElementById('wp').value)

        var wpf = eval(document.getElementById('wpf').value)

        var hp = eval(document.getElementById('hp').value)

        var hpf = eval(document.getElementById('hpf').value)

        var o = eval(document.getElementById('o').value)

        var of = eval(document.getElementById('of').value)

        if (!wf || !hf || !wp || !hp || !o) {
          alert('All fields are required!')
          return
        }

        var width = (1 / 2) * ((hf + hff) - (hp + hpf) + (o + of ));
        var height = (1 / 2) * ((wf + wff) - (wp + wpf) + (o + of ));

        document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = new Fraction(width).toString();
        document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = new Fraction(height).toString();

        document.getElementById('rectangle').scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth'
        })

      }
    </script>

  </sides>
  <sides>

    <center>
      <div style="width:400px;height:50px;;border:5px solid #000; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 50px;padding-bottom:75%;background-color:gray" id="rectangle">
        <center>
          <div id="width"></div>
        </center>

        <div id="height"></div>
      </div>
    </center>
  </sides>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see in the above code snippet, When you leave the fields blank, it throws the error message as you should.  However, when the user types in a `0` into the field, then it produces the same error which it should not.

The code in question is **:**

```
if (!wf || !hf || !wp || !hp || !o) {
          alert('All fields are required!')
          return
        }
```

My `required` fields only consist of the input fields & do not apply to the select dropdown menus.

Can someone provide some guidance on how to `require` that **only** blank fields are receiving my error message when the above code is in use ?

Comment: `isNaN` may help

Comment: So you can not do a truthy check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use validation even when not using native form submission by using the [Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation) to query the validation state.

Don't use `eval` to convert strings into numbers, especially not user input.  Use `parseInt`, `parseFloat` or the [unitary operator `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus).

Additionally `<input type="number">` elements have the property `valueAsNumber` that you can use instead of `value`. All these will return [`NaN` which can checked with `isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) if the value isn't a number, or can't be converted to one.

Comment: This  was great information.  As a hobbyist - this was very helpful.  I wanted to add to this accepted answer by showing what I did.  I changed the `if` statement to this:  `if (isNaN(wf) || isNaN(hf) || isNaN(wp) || isNaN(hp) || isNaN(o)) { alert('All fields are required!') return}`

JSfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/3Lk6ha0v/

Answer (score -1):

Just change your logic

From :

```
 if (!wf || !hf || !wp || !hp || !o) {
                  alert('All fields are required!')
                  return
                }
```

To :

```
if (!(wf || hf || wp || hp || o)) {
                  alert('All fields are required!')
                  return
                }
```

```css
#height {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name "viewport" content="width=device-width,

        initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>I Was Framed - Calculator</title>



  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400i,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <sides>

    <section>

      <form id="frm1" action="/index.html" method="post">

        <fieldset>

          <legend>

            I Was Framed Calculator

          </legend>



          <label for="frameWidth">Frame Width:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="wf" id="wf">
          <select name="wff" id="wff">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
          </select>

          <label for="frameHeight">Frame Height:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="hf" id="hf">
          <select name="hff" id="hff">

            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
          </select>



          <label for="pictureWidth">Picture Width:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="wp"
            id="wp">
          <select name="wpf" id="wpf">

            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
          </select>

          <label for="pictureHeight">Picture Height:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="hp"
            id="hp">
          <select name="hpf" id="hpf">

            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
          </select><br>

          <label for="matOverlap">Mat Overlap:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="o" id="o">
          <select name="of" id="of">

            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
            <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
          </select>

          <br>


          <br>
          <input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Calculate" name="cmdCalc" />

        </fieldset>

      </form>

    </section>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/fractional@1.0.0/index.js"></script>

    <script>
      function calc()

      {

        var wf = eval(document.getElementById('wf').value)

        var wff = eval(document.getElementById('wff').value)

        var hf = eval(document.getElementById('hf').value)

        var hff = eval(document.getElementById('hff').value)

        var wp = eval(document.getElementById('wp').value)

        var wpf = eval(document.getElementById('wpf').value)

        var hp = eval(document.getElementById('hp').value)

        var hpf = eval(document.getElementById('hpf').value)

        var o = eval(document.getElementById('o').value)

        var of = eval(document.getElementById('of').value)

        if (!(wf || hf || wp || hp || o)) {
          alert('All fields are required!')
          return
        }

        var width = (1 / 2) * ((hf + hff) - (hp + hpf) + (o + of ));
        var height = (1 / 2) * ((wf + wff) - (wp + wpf) + (o + of ));

        document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = new Fraction(width).toString();
        document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = new Fraction(height).toString();

        document.getElementById('rectangle').scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth'
        })

      }
    </script>

  </sides>
  <sides>

    <center>
      <div style="width:400px;height:50px;;border:5px solid #000; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 50px;padding-bottom:75%;background-color:gray" id="rectangle">
        <center>
          <div id="width"></div>
        </center>

        <div id="height"></div>
      </div>
    </center>
  </sides>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This changes the logic. It no longer shows the error message when some of the fields are empty.